# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'context' referenced before assignment - Odoov8 to Odoov10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have this method I've migrated from v8 to v10 community:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    """ To create a new record,
    adds a Boolean field to true
    indicates that the partner is a company
    """
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    context.update({'create_company': True})
    return super(ResUsers, self).create(vals) 

@api.multi
def write(self, values): 
    """ To write a new record,
    adds a Boolean field to true
    indicates that the partner is a company
    """
    context = dict(context or {})
    context.update({'create_company': True})
    return super(ResUsers, self).write(values)
```

When I click on these booleans, It throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/model/res_users.py", line 52, in write
context = dict(context or {})
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'context' referenced before assignment
```

I've changed `context = context {}` to `context = dict(context or {})` although I'm not sure if it's needed at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only you can access the context by self._context or self.env.context. But here I think you defined wrongly

Answer (score 1):

You can write create & write method using following syntax.

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    """ To create a new record,
    adds a Boolean field to true
    indicates that the partner is a company
    """
    context=dict(self._context or {})
    context.update({'create_company': True})
    return super(ResUsers, self.with_context(context)).create(vals)

@api.multi
def write(self, values): 
    """ To write a new record,
    adds a Boolean field to true
    indicates that the partner is a company
    """
    context=dict(self._context or {})
    context.update({'create_company': True})
    return super(ResUsers, self.with_context(context)).write(vals)
```

> > Using with_context you can pass context to super method
> >
> > Using self._context you will get context, By default context is frozendict. you must convert in dict other wise you will get error.
> >
> > When you are calling super method using with_context,At that time you must pass existing context as well other wise super method will not get all child methods context.